# Не работает отладка в Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

Раньше при отладке все было нормально. Теперь пишет: выберите допустимый элемент запуска. Тоже самое в notepad++. Какая причина?

Comment: службы Windows не отключали?
Не работала отладка когда соответствующую службу отключил

Comment: Нет, не отключала

Comment: Мне кажется, нужно добавить больше подробностей в вопрос